# MySQL function to to evaluate a string as integer based on array of data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE my_records, units
SET my_records.unit_id = units.id
WHERE my_records.column_1 = units.column_1 AND my_records.column_2 = units.column_2
AND my_records.id > 0 AND my_records.id <= 1000
ORDER BY my_records.id
```

The problem is `my_records.column_1` is an integer and `units.column_1` is a string. But they reference the same array of data:

```
[ 'Medical', 'Legal', 'Auto', 'Electrical', 'Software', 'Education' ]
```

So `my_records.column_1` can be 0 and `units.column_1` can be 'Medical'. But I can discern that 'Medical' is 0 because it is the first element of the array.

Is there a function I can pass to MySQL to convert that string of 'Medical' to the appropriate index like 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the query using `JOIN` and table aliases

```
UPDATE my_records r JOIN
       units u
       ON r.column_1 = u.column_1 AND r.column_2 = u.column_2
    SET r.unit_id = u.id
WHERE r.id > 0 AND r.id <= 1000
ORDER BY my_records.id;
```

Now, you want to do the conversion.  Probably the simplest method is a function such as `FIELD()`:

```
UPDATE my_records r JOIN
       units u
       ON r.column_1 = FIELD(u.column_1, 'Medical', 'Legal', 'Auto', 'Electrical', 'Software', 'Education') AND
          r.column_2 = u.column_2
    SET r.unit_id = u.id
WHERE r.id > 0 AND r.id <= 1000
ORDER BY my_records.id;
```

Note:  You might need to adjust the value returned by `FIELD()` because it is 1-based.

That said, you have a problem with your data model if you are storing values like this with no reference table.  You really should be joining to a reference table to disambiguate the codes.

Comment: Because this is 1-based index, I should add "- 1" to the query right? Like this: ON r. column_1 = FIELD(u.column_1, 'Medical', 'Legal', 'Auto', 'Electrical', 'Software', 'Education') - 1

Comment: @Donato . . . If `u.column_1` is zero-based, then you should subtract 1.